# Reduce level of nested object array in Typescript/JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and Angular and I'm struggling with a problem.
Say, I have an array of `Application` objects. 
Each `Application` object has this kind of a nested structure:

Application
|
----[Document Type]
---------|
--------------[Document]
------------------|
------------------------Metadata

(Each `Application` has an array of `Document Type`.
Each `Document Type` has an array of `Document`.
Each `Document` has a `Metadata` inside it)

Example:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Application 1",
  "parent_type": "root",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "Operations Manual",
    "parent": "Application 1",
    "parent_type": "application",
    "count": 2,
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "App1-OpManual-1",
      "metadata": {
       "actualDocName": "operations1-app1",
       "currentStatus": "for review",
       "lastModifiedBy": "user 1",
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "App1-OpManual-2",
      "metadata": {
       "actualDocName": "operations2-app1",
       "currentStatus": "for review",
       "lastModifiedBy": "user 2",
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I'm trying to reduce this array to this (basically, to retain the nesting only till level 2 and discard the rest):

Application
|
----[Document Type]

..so that, the JSON becomes like this:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Application 1",
  "parent_type": "root",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "Operations Manual",
    "parent": "Application 1",
    "parent_type": "application",
    "count": 2
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I've been trying with multiple examples from tutorials, but haven't been able to get the correct JS to do this. Can anybody please help?

Comment: `I've been trying` show what you've tried, perhaps it's a simple mistake you've made in your attempt - you'll learn more from having your mistake corrected rather than having the code written for you with no apparent attempt by you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to grab the properties and values you need from your outer-most objects within your array, and then use `.map()` again with destructuring to get the properties you need fro your inner-most object to map each application object in your array to a newly created minified version of itself:

```js
const arr = [{name:"Application 1",parent_type:"root",children:[{name:"Operations Manual",parent:"Application 1",parent_type:"application",count:2,children:[{name:"App1-OpManual-1",metadata:{actualDocName:"operations1-app1",currentStatus:"for review",lastModifiedBy:"user 1",size:56,fileExtension:"docx"}},{name:"App1-OpManual-2",metadata:{actualDocName:"operations2-app1",currentStatus:"for review",lastModifiedBy:"user 2",size:56,fileExtension:"pdf"}}]}]}];

const res = arr.map(({children, ...r}) => (
    {
      ...r,
      children: children.map(({children, ...keep}) => ({...keep}))
    }
  ));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.  
While I'm learning the ABC's of TypeScript and JS and yet to reach this `destructuring` concept, I'm trying to understand how this works.
After I posted the question, I thought I should have mentioned the condition based on which I need to discard children `(parent_type == 'application')`.

But I see its not necessary at all. I think, that we did the nested map() operations twice, that itself achieved the navigation till level 2. Isn't it?

Comment: @Tatha yes, that's right. The nested map assumes that the outer object (ie the `parent_type`) is the application, so we don't need to check that