# Convert object with arrays to new objects and attach it

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, split

I will this typescript object convert:

```
api:{
  accessToken:[user1::aaaaa,user2::bbbbb],
accessSecret:[user1:aaaaa,userb::bbbbb]
}
```

i will split the string inside the arrays by :: sign.

Finish object should look like this

```
api:{
accessToken:[user1::aaaaa,user2::bbbbb],
accessSecret:[user1:aaaaa,userb::bbbbb],
user1_access:aaaaa,
user2_access:bbbbb,
user1_secret:aaaaa,
user2_secret:bbbbb
}
```

What is the best solution without compile errors in typescript, please Help.

Comment: I would use the combination of an `Object.keys(api)` and then `.reduce` on that resulting array to accumulate the output you are looking for. I suggest showing the community what you have tried, as we usually don't just write code solutions to questions that have no effort shown. Please check out the posting guidelines.

Comment: I would not post it here if i had not tried before

Comment: This answer looks to solve a similar problem to that which you are asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577284/reduce-level-of-nested-object-array-in-typescript-js

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample which gives you an idea of how to go about it,

```
const api = {
  accessToken:["user1::aaaaa","user2::bbbbb"],
  accessSecret:["user1::xxxx","user2::yyyy"]
};

const newApiObj: any = {};

const accessTokenvalues = api.accessToken.map(x => x.split("::")) ?? [];
for(const item of accessTokenvalues){
  newApiObj[item[0] + '_access'] = item[1];
}

const accessSecretvalues = api.accessSecret.map(x => x.split("::")) ?? [];
for(const item of accessSecretvalues){
  newApiObj[item[0] + '_secret'] = item[1];
}

console.log(newApiObj);
```